# Objective C & Swift -- do they handle both Client and Server Side?

Tags: objective-c, swift, mobile

This is a very general question.

In more "traditional" web or browser based development, you have server side languages such as Java, C#, etc.  Then, on the client side, there is HTML, CSS & JavaScript.

What I'm wondering about native mobile app development (note: NOT mobile web development) is this...

Is there such a clear delineation between server side and client side? Are there separate tools and languages for each? If separate, what tools are used for UI development?

Or, for iOS, do Objective C and/or Swift handle both?

Comment: No it is separate.

Comment: Normally Obj-C and Swift are just for client side and you'd have a separate backend service using those server-side languages you mentioned. However you _can_ do [server-side with Swift language](http://perfect.org/) as well although it's not very common. You'd normally want to use XCode as your IDE for drag&drop WYSIWYG UI development, although you can also code your UI programatically (just like HTML and CSS).

Comment: You can do server-side Objective-C. http://objective-cloud.com

Comment: It is entirely possible to make a mobile app that has no server component. One example might be a calculator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server never returns any view in Mobile development. Its just the api which can be called when data from any server is needed. Rest of the things (Local Storage and Screens mainly) lay on device. Xcode from apple (to develop apple based apps) gives you InterfaceBuilder in form of .storyboard files which can be used with both languages, Objective-C and Swift.

Comment: Sure that makes sense. I guess what I'm wondering is... what tools are used to develop the UI?  Is it just built into the IDE?  You arrange images on the screen, etc?

Comment: If you are going to do mobile development using Swift then you will use Xcode.

Comment: Updated my answer @CaseyCrookston

Answer (score 2):

As you have noticed, there is a very clear separation between server and client side code. They have different requirements:

- Server software needs no UI, or maybe needs to generate a web page.
- Server software needs to run a large number of users on relatively few high-powered machines
- Clients need to implement responsive UI
- Clients are often mobile and need to deal with bad network
- Clients are usually running *comparatively* weak hardware (to save battery)
- Clients can usually sort of monopolize their hardware (compared to servers)

There's more, but you can already see that servers and clients have sometimes even contradictory requirements. So often they are implemented in different languages or frameworks that fit those requirements better.

There are also historical reasons. Often the backends already existed as web servers and were just expanded to work as backends for an app later, or were designed as backends for different clients, and that's why they are written in a different language.

That said, there is no reason why you couldn't write your backends in the same language as your apps. There are obvious synergies when it comes to sharing data structures, or matching server-side algorithms (e.g. So a game can predict the server's response when the connection is slow).

Some apps do that, it just depends on your app and circumstances whether it's appropriate.

Given the differences, there are tools specific to each side, but again, you can do most of the work with the same tools if you want. For Swift/Objective-C, that would usually be an editor and compiler/linker. Most people use Xcode for that, but if you're not on a Mac, you would use other tools, like vi or emacs for the text editing, and clang as the compiler.

The main uses of Objective-C and Swift are client side, so you have UIKit and their standard libraries there to do most of the work. Server-side Swift is fairly new, and server-side Objective-C is not very common, so you might have a harder time finding helpful libraries for those (at least compared to languages developed for backend use, like Python or Ruby).